# Several Audiences in JWT token to authenticate with azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, openid-connect

## Requirements

- I want to authenticate against Azure AD, (but later deployments can authenticate against any openID connect server)
- I am using oidc-client-ts (I don't want to use anything else as I want to be able to authenticate against any Oidc server)
- I am using code flow (not really relevant in this question)
- I want my SPA to get a JWT token that permits to make graphApi calls (to get the profile of the user)
- And of course I want my SPA to access my API server

This means the JWT token must be accepted by 2 audiences: GraphAPI, my API server

## First attempt

Here are the settings I am giving to my UserManager:

```js
const oidcSetups = {
    authority: buildUrl(config.oAuthAuthority, config),
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    client_id: config.oAuthClientId,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}`,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email'
};
```

The token given by azure ad permits me to get the profile (make a graphAPI call) because it has the audience claim set to target GraphAPI, but it doesn't have the audience claim for my API serveur.

## Second attempt

Then, I tried this setting (the change is in the scope):

```js
const oidcSetups = {
    authority: buildUrl(config.oAuthAuthority, config),
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    client_id: config.oAuthClientId,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : ''}`,
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read'
};
```

Then my JWT token has indeed the audience claim that is realated to `api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read`. So this is what I want, except that GraphAPI refuses requests as it doesn't have the audience claim that corresponds to GraphAPI.

## Question

How can I manage to get a JWT token that permits me to be accepted by several targets/audiences?

As I believe it is not possible to issue a token that target several audiences,what is the way for to access 2 different audiences with the user authenticating only once?

Comment: 1) you say you want to use any OIDC Provider but you are asking about a feature specific to Azure (GraphAPI), 2) this is related to permissions but I'm not sure that this has anything to do with audiences. In your app registration, have you specifically enabled the correct API Permissions?

Comment: "Audience" as returned in a Token Set is used to confirm that the Access Token was generated for *your app* - it's an additional security check. You can't have it return a different audience. Azure even describes `aud` as "Used to perform audience validation; emits the client ID of the resource (API) in GUID format".

Comment: In this situation, the scope "profile" means that you get a claim to access what is -behind the scenes- GraphAPI. For other authentication servers, it can be something else, anyway, it is standard and oidc-client-ts knows how to do in any situation to get the profile... but the token must have the audience for it.

Comment: @Codebling that's what I'm figuring out. But how can I do to get the profile, and also call my rest APIs?

Comment: That's not my understanding of how it works. We're mixing two systems here. One is your API, which is a Relying Party in OpenID Connect terms, and requires the user to be authenticated. The other is GraphAPI, which is a "resource server with protected resources" in OAuth terms. Your API is protected by an *authen**tication*** requirement, GraphAPI is protected by a *auth**orization*** requirement.

Comment: You can't convince GraphAPI to grant permission based on a different request (this would give clients the power to access things they shouldn't), you need to configure Azure to grant an Access Tokens with permissions to access GraphAPI.

Comment: To help us debug, you should include the code that calls Graph API and the resulting error

Comment: @Codebling like mentionned in my post, I am not doing any call myself to GraphAPI. Oidc-client-ts makes it for me to get the profile. I am not doing anything myself. And the whole setup I transmit to oidc-client-ts is mentionned in my post

Comment: @Codebling, FYI, the wellknown metadata file has a standard attribute to permit any oidc compliant client to get in a generic way the profile of the user: "userinfo_endpoint". And the one that AzureAD gives is "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",

Comment: `scope: 'openid profile email api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read'` is wrong, openid, profile, are scopes for graph api, but api://xxx is for your custom api, you can't set 2 kinds of scopes at the same time, because it will make the token contained 2 audiences which is not correct. `aud` claim in Aad access token is a string but not `[]`.

Comment: @TinyWang yes, api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read is correct :). It works, and it is even documented. And, as mentionned in the post, `openid profile email api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read` works gracefully, as I get the audience `api://mycompany.pms` that corresponds to the scope `api://mycompany.pms/mycompany.api.read` (once again it is documented). My problem is that with this token, I can't query GraphAPI.

Comment: `api://mycompany.pms/xxx` will make the `aud` claim had value `api://mycompany.pms`, but when you want to call graph api, the `aud` should have value like `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Comment: I am aware that the Userinfo Endpoint is on Graph API. You should refer to this as the Userinfo Endpoint, not as the Graph API, which is a full-blown API which has nothing to do with OIDC. You're aware that the call to the Userinfo Endpoint requires an Access Token and is done after the token callback, right? In [`openid-client`](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client), this call must be made explicitly (separately). I don' tknow how this works in oidc-client-ts

Comment: You should consider rephrasing the question "How do I get userinfo data from Oidc-client-ts", and avoid misleading terms like "audiences" and GraphAPI in your question.

Comment: I know how to get user info using oidc-client-ts. I know how to get the right audience in my token. My problem is that I don't know how to deal to make BOTH with my users authenticating once.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a couple of years ago and wrote [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/). Microsoft use [resource indicators](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-resource-indicators-08) for their own APIs, so you need to handle the MS APIs differently to your own custom APIs. This is the real issue here I think, rather than audience configuration.

Your SPA scopes look fine, and standards based, but I think you'll need to get Graph data via one of your APIs. This requires a different access token, which an API can retrieve via [user assertions](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L83) (on-behalf-of flow), and use of a client secret.